# Not getting write speed and write method options in infrarecorder while burning image to disc

Tags: installation

I am trying to burn iso image on CD using infra recorder.i referred site http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows for instructions but i am not getting "Write speed" & "Write method" options while burning,hence unable to click OK button.Can nyone please help?

Comment: Which windows are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-installing Infra Recorder.  You can [download it here](http://infrarecorder.org/?page_id=5).

Or

You can [download](http://www.freeisoburner.com/) Free ISO Burner, a completely free program that only burns ISO files, making it really easy to use.

Note: Free ISO Burner is completely free and fully functional. It works on Windows 7, Vista, and XP, and will burn an ISO image file to any of the various kinds of BD, DVD, and CD discs that exist.

Comment: Thanks Mitch for replying but i am getting this error using Free ISO Burner:Failed to write ISO image, Error: Hardware Error 14848.and i am using windows XP

Comment: Check the MD5SUM. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM. Have you tried re-downloading the ISO file?